# How could I resolve xmlrpc.client.Fault while trying to search a package through pip3?

Tags: pip, pypi

04LTS with python 3.8.5, and whenever I am trying to run `pip3 search <package>`, it's giving me an error, I'm not sure why:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 52, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 71, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1109, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1450, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/xmlrpc.py", line 38, in request
    return self.parse_response(response.raw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1341, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 655, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32500: "RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.">
```

How could I go about solving this issue? I understand something called XMLRPC is being/going to be disabled/deprecated, but I'm not sure what that is. If I cannot use pip3 search from the terminal, is my only other way of searching packages directly through [PyPi](https://pypi.org/)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpypi%5d%20search

Comment: https://status.python.org/incidents/grk0k7sz6zkp

Comment: @phd I did see that something called XMLRPC is disabled, but what *is* that?

Comment: In general, [XML-RPC is a remote procedure call (RPC) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC). PyPI supported an API over XML-RPC which `pip` uses for search but it's now disabled at PyPI and the `search` command perhaps will be removed from `pip`.